# How to download file using asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, filestream

I use two actions to download a file. no errors display, but no files also get downloaded!!

first action

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult DownloadDoc()
    {
        string DocPath = "wwwroot/Uploads/5c92f430-4aef-41c8-b201-853597935771.jpg";
        var image = System.IO.File.OpenRead(DocPath);
        return File(image, "image/jpg");
    }
```

second action

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult DownloadDoc()
    {    
        string DocPath = "wwwroot/Uploads/5c92f430-4aef-41c8-b201-853597935771.jpg";
        string fileName = "blablabla";

        var net = new WebClient();
        var data = net.DownloadData(DocPath);
        var content = new MemoryStream(data);
        var contentType = "APPLICATION/octet-stream";
        return File(content, contentType,fileName);
     }
```

Any one of them returns nothing, however, during tracing file is found.

How can I get a save dialog box to ask me where I would like to save my file on my local machine?

Comment: How exactly are you calling this endpoint?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto  var Parameters = { "DocPath": currentFile };
        $.get('@Url.Action("DownloadDoc","Documents")', Parameters, function (result) {
            $('#mymsg').html(result);
        });

Comment: You’re downloading the file via AJAX, so of course the user doesn’t get a download dialog by the browser because your AJAX code is responsible of doing something with the response. If you want to trigger a download dialog, you should just redirect the user to that URL. For example by doing `window.location = "@Url.Action(…)"`.